# How to specify rules in .proverc?

Tags: perl, perl-prove

The [manpage of Perls prove](https://perldoc.perl.org/prove.html) tool says:

> Options in .proverc are specified in the same way as command line options:
>
> ```
> # .proverc
> --state=hot,fast,save
> -j9
> ```

This is not true, a rule specified as

```
--rules='par=**'
```

will work on the command line but is **not** recognized in the `.proverc` file. In fact, adding this line to `.proverc` will disable parallel testing for all files.

Comment: Works for me on TAP::Harness v3.38 and Perl v5.26.1.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple: Replace the first equal sign with a blank and specify rules inside of `.proverc` as follows:

```
--rules 'par=**'
```

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Test-Harness/bin/prove, actually. I think this doc is generated from the POD in the distribution that's shipped as part of Perl, it's not included in Perl itself.

Comment: Bugs for this distribution should be submitted [here](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Test-Harness), and bugs in Perl also should not be submitted to the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues) not through the perlbug utility (docs for this are in process of being updated).